# How to map 403 error to user friendly error?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, http-status-code-403

I'm new to building rest APi using spring boot.

Here is my `controller` snippet

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/post/posts", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PostDto> createPost(@Valid @RequestBody PostDto postDto) {

        System.out.println("postDto : "  + postDto.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(postService.createPost(postDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

this is my `Security` config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)    //give method level security
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // In Memory Users
        UserDetails ashish = User.builder().username("oxana").password(getPasswordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER").build();
        UserDetails admin = User.builder().username("admin").password(getPasswordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN").build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(ashish, admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I'm trying land above exception here

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Errors> handleGlobalException(Exception exception,
                                                               WebRequest webRequest){
        Error errorDetails = new Error();
        errorDetails.setErrorDesc(exception.getMessage());
        errorDetails.setErrorCode(Error.ErrorCodeEnum.BAD_REQUEST);
        Errors errors = new Errors();
        errors.addErrorsItem(errorDetails);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

but its not coming and giving a big mess of error, like this

```
"timestamp": "2022-02-21T11:39:28.797+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "trace": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.
```

Can anyone please suggest me, How can I handle or catch this exception to customize error, where user has no access to do something ?

Thanks

Update

Implemented `AccessDeniedHandler` in below way

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, reason = "Dont have sufficient priviliges to perform this action")
public class AccessDeniedError implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exec)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendRedirect("Dont have sufficient priviliges to perform this action");

    }

}
```

And now able to get message like this

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-02-21T13:29:08.377+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/post/Dont%20have%20sufficient%20priviliges%20to%20perform%20this%20action"
}
```

Its somewhat better, but how can I take control of these variables `("error", "message", "status")` values from above response, so that I could add mine custom values in it ?

Comment: `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AccessDeniedException` is handled by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` which then delegates to the `AccessDeniedHandler` to write to corresponding response to the client.

If you want to customize this behavior, then you can implement a `AccessDeniedHandler` and then set your implementation to the `HttpSecurity` object.

**MyAccessDeniedHandler.java**

```java
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        writeCustomResponse(response);
    }

    private void writeCustomResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (!response.isCommitted()) {
            try {
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
                response.getWriter().write("{ \"error\": \"User is not authorized.\"}");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Since [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was deprecated in Spring Security 5.7.0-M2](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), the following shows how to configure it by registering a `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler())

    return http.build();
}
```

### OLD WAY

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // set the customized AccessDeniedHandler to the HttpSecurity object
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: @OxanaGrey . . . the `sendRedirect` method sends a redirect response - [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)). I've updated the MyAccessDeniedHandler.java example to show how you can write a custom json response.

Comment: so there is no way of get control over these 3 attributes (error, status, message) ?

Comment: afaik, not exactly take control over the spring's response object, but nothing stops you from creating your own object and then serialize it as a json. My example already tells you how you can write your own response. Now, you can create a class with the fields you want (error, status, message), write a json by using a object mapper and then write to the response (as shown above). It seems like you're not familiarized with java ee filters, I suggest you to take a look at them.