# Problem with Costume Exception handler for 403 Forbidden in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Boot framework for my backend application and Keycloak for my user and access management system. I have a problem regarding creating a costume exception handler for 403 forbidden error.

I already read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306302/spring-security-creating-403-access-denied-custom-response) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205918/how-to-map-403-error-to-user-friendly-error). These questions are about creating custom message when 403 error is raised. Both of the answers did not help me since I have a general exception handler.

**Without any general exception handler**, I get proper 401 and 403 responses regarding unauthorized tokens.
But I want to have a general exception handler for unexpected errors. Following is my general exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> generalExceptionHandler(Exception e) {

    log.error(e.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("General Error");
}
```

Without any other exception handler all situations that result in 401 or 403 response are handled by my *generalExceptionHandler*, which is not preferred. Since I want to send the proper message to the frontend in case of occurrence of 401 or 403 errors.

Therefore I developed an exception handler for Access denied exception like following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> accessDeniedExceptionHandler(Exception e) {

    log.error(e.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Access is denied"));
}
```

In this step all situations regarding the 401 situation are handled successfully with *accessDeniedExceptionHandler*.

**The problem is that, situations regarding 403 Forbidden now are handled by *accessDeniedExceptionHandler* too**. Since I want to send the proper message to frontend in case of 403 situation, I want to have a separate handler for this case. The reason relies in importance of distinguishing 401 and 403 errors in my software.

Can somebody please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**My Solution**

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306302/spring-security-creating-403-access-denied-custom-response?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607022/19584950)  I developed the following classes and beans.

This is the custom authentication entry point class for producing desired response for 401 exceptions:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint 

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    // Create response content
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("code", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    obj.put("message", "Access Denied");


    res.getWriter().write(obj.toString());

    }
}
```

This is the custom access denied handler class for producing desired response for 403 exceptions:

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
@Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                   AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {


    // Set response code
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);

    // Set response content type to JSON
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    // Create response content
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("code", HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    obj.put("message", "Access Forbidden");

    // Add content to the response
    response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());

    }
}
```

As it is explained in the above mentioned answer (Thanks to [Amit Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8597810/amit-samuel)), I added the following to my http security config:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

Also, I added the following beans to web security class:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
    return new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();
}
@Bean
public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
    return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
}
```

In this step without a general exception handler I produce custom responses for 401 and 403 exceptions. **But by enabling general exception handler 401 and 403 exceptions are caught by general exception handler.**

Therefore I added the following exception handler alongside with the general exception handler.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> generalExceptionHandler(Exception e) {

    log.error(e.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("General Error");
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
public void accessDeniedExceptionHandler(Exception e) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException(e.getMessage());
}
```

By this means, whenever 401 and 403 exceptions are raised, the accessDeniedExceptionHandler will be activated and would throw a new access denied exception. Then, according to the situation, 401 or 403, proper response and code will be returned.

For now, this solution works fine for my project, but I would search for the best practice. I would be so grateful if any one has other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to handle access-denied requests:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AccessDeniedExceptionHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

@Override
public void handle(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse res,
        AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException {
    APIErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = new APIErrorResponse(Collections.singletonList("Access Denied!"));
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    String message = new Gson().toJson(apiErrorResponse);
    res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, message);
   }
}
```